# Is it possible to type in dashes if I have a TextBox that is a Child of a Checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have this currently:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="346,17,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="295" Height="189"   >
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
</CheckBox>
```

I currently can not type in a "-" in my `TextBox` because it is a child of my `CheckBox` and `CheckBox` has some built in feature where if the **+/=** key OR **-/_** key is pressed it checks/unchecks my `CheckBox`. I don't want this feature, I want the user to be able to actually type in dashes like "-" without it unchecking/checking my checkbox. Is there a easy way to get around this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, after hours of losing my mind I figured out how to get rid of this problem.

All you have to do is set `IsThreeState = True;` because they are doing a check for `IsThreeState` in the  [CheckBox.cs code here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/SP/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/CheckBox@cs/1/CheckBox@cs)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a custom checkbox and override *OnKeyDown*:

```
public class MCheckBox : CheckBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)   { }
}
```

Another way is to just not put the TextBox within the CheckBox, but beside it, both in a DockPanel with some modifications:

```
<StackPanel>
    <CheckBox>
         <TextBox Text="this is a TextBox within a CheckBox"/>
    </CheckBox>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Text="this is a TextBox beside a CheckBox" Margin="4,0,0,0"/>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```